# How to force bones to follow tracking points?

Tags: armature, 2d, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to animate a 2D figure. My figure is a flat subdivided mesh with an image on it. There's an armature representing the figure, and I have a set of tracking points linked to empties in the model which indicate how the figure is supposed to move. (Knee, foot, hand, elbow etc.)

What I want is for each bone to precisely follow its particular tracking point, stretching as necessary. However, I can't seem to make this happen. I've tried the Inverse Kinematic bone constraint, but even with the bones set to maximum stretchiness this is refusing to stretch the bones far enough to reach the tracking points, leading to garbage results and flailing as the solver tries to find a solution.

I've tried Stretch To, but this doesn't work either --- I suspect it does something else entirely. There are no other suitable constraints (and I've tried a number of unsuitable ones).

Is there a way to do what I want with armatures, and if so, how? Or, given that bones appear to be intended to be stiff rather than stretchy, am I using the wrong tool for the job, and if so, what tool *should* I be using?

Comment: Stretch-to is the answer.  If that's not working for you, we need to see the file to be able to figure out why.

Comment: After doing some tinkering, yes, stretch-to does work --- but it doesn't work the way I expected. Instead of stretching the bone so that the end coincides with the object being tracked, it applies some kind of multiplication factor based on the 'original length' property of the bone, which is always wrong. So, I have to add the stretch-to constraint and then manually adjust 'original length' until the end of the bone is on top of the tracking point. It then works the way I expect. I'm sure there are reasons for this, but I don't know what they are.

Comment: It stretches according to the rest length given; the default rest length given is calculated from the current distance.  If you want to know the exact rest length there are a number of things you can do, but usually, it's simplest just to alt g alt r alt s reset the pose so that the stretch to marker is exactly at the tail of the bone (since you put it there in edit mode, right?) then click the X button next to the rest length.